# Positioning of x axis labels

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to change positioning of the x axis labels in the following bar chart by moving it "down" (away from x axis). Unfortunately I am not able to do so, as I tried `at={(ticklabel cs:<position>)}` as well as `every axis x label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:0.5,-0.5)}},`.

Any recommendations?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.3,
}

%Maintenance Subskala Kreuztabelle

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    Name      x   niedrige  st1  hohe   st2
    niedrig$\:$Traumabelastung  1  22.2  0   14.8  0     
    hohe$\:$Traumabelastung     2   23.1  0     18.8  0    

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
    title=A,
    bar width=50pt,
    ybar=0pt,       
    ylabel={\% Abbrecher},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=40,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    width=11cm,
    height=8cm,
    xticklabels from table={data.txt}{Name},      
    xtick=data,
    xlabel near ticks,
%   extra x ticks={0.82, 1.5}, % I want to label bars with some extra numbers here therefore I need to move down "niedrige/hohe Traumabelastung".
%   extra x tick style={yshift=10mm, major tick length=0pt,
%   },
%   extra x tick labels={
%       \textbf{2},
%       \textbf{10}
%   },
    ticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 1000 sep = {}},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift=transformdirectiony(\myshift+1.5),
        anchor=north,
        rotate=0,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    ymajorgrids=true,
    legend pos= north west,% Legende oben links in Abb.
    legend cell align=left% Rechtsbündige Ausrichtung der Legende
    ]
    \addplot
    [draw = black,
    fill = gray!30!white,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
%   error mark=triangle*,
    error bar style={color=black}]  
    table[
    x=x,
    y=niedrige,
    y error=st1,
    visualization depends on=1.25*\thisrow{st1} \as \myshift,
    ]
    {data.txt};
    \addlegendentry{niedrige Maintenance};
    \addplot
    [draw = black,
    fill=white,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
%   error mark=triangle*,
    error bar style={color=black}]  
    table[
    x=x,
    y=hohe,
    y error=st2,
    visualization depends on=1.25*\thisrow{st2} \as \myshift,
    ]
    {data.txt};
    \addlegendentry{hohe Maintenance};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Abbrecherquoten der verschiedenen Gruppen. Es werden Abbrecherquoten in Prozent und 95\% Konfidenzintervalle f\"ur drei Gruppen f\"ur hohe Traumabelastung und niedrige Traumabelastung unterteilt nach niedrigem und hohem Motivationswert angegeben. Zahlen unterhalb der Balken geben die Anzahl der Patienten in der jeweiligen Gruppe an. \textbf{A}) Maintenance Subskala, \textbf{B}) Contemplation Subskala, \textbf{C}) RTC Wert.}

    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels "niedrige/hohe Traumabelastung" are ticklabels and not axis labels. To shift them down you can use

```
xticklabel style={/tikz/yshift=-15pt},% <- added
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.3,% 1.3 is really old
}
%Maintenance Subskala Kreuztabelle
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    Name      x   niedrige  st1  hohe   st2
    {niedrige Traumabelastung}  1  22.2  0   14.8  0     
    {hohe Traumabelastung}     2   23.1  0     18.8  0    

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
    title=A,
    bar width=50pt,
    ybar=0pt,       
    ylabel={\% Abbrecher},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=40,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    width=11cm,
    height=8cm,
    xticklabels from table={data.txt}{Name},
    xtick=data,
    xlabel near ticks,
    extra x ticks={0.82, 1.5}, % I want to label bars with some extra numbers here therefore I need to move down "niedrige/hohe Traumabelastung".
    extra x tick style={yshift=15pt,% <- changed to 15pt
    major tick length=0pt,
    },
    extra x tick labels={
       \textbf{2},
       \textbf{10}
    },
    ticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 1000 sep = {}},
    xticklabel style={/tikz/yshift=-15pt},% <- added
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift=transformdirectiony(\myshift+1.5),
        anchor=north,
        rotate=0,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    ymajorgrids=true,
    legend pos= north west,% Legende oben links in Abb.
    legend cell align=left% Rechtsbündige Ausrichtung der Legende
    ]
    \addplot
    [draw = black,
    fill = gray!30!white,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
%   error mark=triangle*,
    error bar style={color=black}]  
    table[
    x=x,
    y=niedrige,
    y error=st1,
    visualization depends on=1.25*\thisrow{st1} \as \myshift,
    ]
    {data.txt};
    \addlegendentry{niedrige Maintenance};
    \addplot
    [draw = black,
    fill=white,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
%   error mark=triangle*,
    error bar style={color=black}]  
    table[
    x=x,
    y=hohe,
    y error=st2,
    visualization depends on=1.25*\thisrow{st2} \as \myshift,
    ]
    {data.txt};
    \addlegendentry{hohe Maintenance};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Abbrecherquoten der verschiedenen Gruppen. Es werden Abbrecherquoten in Prozent und 95\% Konfidenzintervalle f\"ur drei Gruppen und niedrige Traumabelastung unterteilt nach niedrigem und hohem Motivationswert angegeben. Zahlen unterhalb der Balken geben die Anzahl der Patienten in der jeweiligen Gruppe an. \textbf{A}) Maintenance Subskala, \textbf{B}) Contemplation Subskala, \textbf{C}) RTC Wert.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```